# Ingest bzip2 files with Apache Flume

Tags: flume-ng, bzip2

I need to ingest compressed files in bzip2. Is it possible using flume?

I have tried it with spooling directory and BlobDeserializer, but it is unreadable at the sink.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As of now flume does not support compressed spool data. if you want you can use custom interceptor to uncompress on the fly.